# What subprocess preexec_fn=os.setpgrp does

Tags: python, subprocess

I am a little confused on what `subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)` does.

where cmd is something like ["mybashscript", "arg1", "arg2"]

Initially I was just using `subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`, but I  had an issue, where I run the bash script in a subprocess.  And that if I interrupt (ctr+c) the python script, it will kill the bash script as well, but it does not do the clean up.  The clean up is in the bash script itself.

But if I run the bash script directly, and hit ctr+c, it will stop the script and execute the clean up.

I tried assigning my own `signal_handler` and assign it to `signal.signal(signal.SIG_INT, signal_handler)` that then performs `p.send_signal(signal.SIG_INT)` to the subprocess but didnt seem to work.

Adding `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp`to the subprocess command, did do the job.  Interrupting the python script, stops the bash script while still executing the clean up.  But was just wondering what it really does?  Or how it works?  Some state that this detaches the child from the parent, and unable to receive signal, but then how did it work?

Comment: Does it still work when you quit the terminal?